# RAD Studio 10.3.3 Delphi App hangs in Main forms finalization (Threads hang on TMethodImplementationIntercept / gdiplus)

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-xe, terminate, rad-studio

I have one Delphi Windows64 Application compiled by RAD Studio 10.3.3 that hangs sometimes in the finalization part of the main form after the call of CheckSynchronize; at the real end of application (nothing is called behind).

With ProcessExplorer on Windows10 19.03 I can verify open threads on TMethodImplementationIntercept and gdiplus.dllGdiPlusStartup0x1c00.

I do not have implemented any own Gdi calls. The integration of Gdi seems to be caused by any used component or from Delphi functionality internally.

Is there a way to localize some reason for that hanging Gdi threads?

If I call some ShowMessage after CheckSynchronize the Application is terminating well. Like in the example below...

```
Untit MainForm;
....
initialization
finalization
CheckSynchronize;
TDialogService.ShowMessage('End');
end.
```

Without ShowMessage the Application is hanging on that threads, but not each time.
If I call the Application from RAD Studio in Debug Mode without ShowMessage it is also terminating well at any time.

Is there any idea for some helping activity?

Comment: Yes. Stop using ShowMessage in the main form's `finalization` section. At that point, the application has almost entirely shut down, because the main form has been destroyed. It's also too late to be calling `CheckSynchronize`, because all of the forms have been destroyed and therefore there's nothing to synchronize with.

Comment: I don't want to use ShowMessage, but it helps that the App is really terminating, ShowMessage make no sense at this point, but helps as stupid work around, that the App is terminating for sure....

Comment: Ken White@ from your hint I have moved CheckSynchronize to the end of the FormDestroy and this seems to give some improvement. Now most of the times the App is terminating, only sometimes it is still hanging....

Comment: Can we have a [mcve]

Comment: no this is not possible, it is only happen in the context of that specific app and there is nothing in my focus, that can cause that hanging, so it would be a help, to get some hint for some tool maybe to search for the reason, but some sample will not work

Comment: You can't get a *hint for some tool* here, as is made very clear in the [help/on-topic]. Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic. Those same guidelines require that questions asking for debugging help must be included by a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. We can't do much more than what I've done already without that [mcve].

Comment: OK I have understood, but it is not possible to build some reproducible example, thank you